# Hidden Markov Model with several observations

Tags: machine-learning, model, hidden-markov-model, latent-variable

I am a little bit familiar with Hidden Markov Models. I have always seen cases with only one layer of hidden states and one layer of observations. Now I wonder to see if there is a possibility to add several layers of observations? and How can I handle the learning of parameters?

[image]

While I was searching the google, I confronted with some cases with several layers of Hidden states (Gahramani's Factorial HMM model); However I am seeking for a one with multi layers of observations.

To myself, it seems possible to learn a GMM for A, B and C observations; but I don't know exactly how to put it to work.

I would appreciate if someone could possibly help me with a logical approach?
Any hints, suggestions or good references would also help.

Thanks everyone :)